# How to change CSV value into a DateTime object

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, model

I am trying to upload data from a CSV into a Django model. On the CSV there is a date field and the values look like this:

2020-11-11 14:06:25+00:00

Which brings up this error:

'“Deadline” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.'

I am saving the value into a DateTimeField. How would I convert the CSV data into a DateTime object?

I appreciate your help on this. Thanks!

```py
    class Command(BaseCommand):
        help = 'Upload data from csv'

        def add_arguments(self, parser):
            parser.add_argument("path", type=str)

        def handle(self, *args, **options):
            path = options['path']

            with open(path) as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';', dialect='excel')
                next(reader)
                for row in reader:

                    job = Project(
                        organization=row[0],
                        category=row[1],
                        project=row[2],
                        description=row[3],
                        deadline=row[4],
                        creation_timestamp=row[5],
                        state=row[6],
                        submitter=row[7],
                        editor=row[8],
                        paid=paid,
                        notes=row[10]
                    )

                job.save()
```

Comment: how do you try to upload it? Where is your code?

Comment: if you load it as text then you could crop last 6 chars - `"2020-11-11 14:06:25+00:00"[:-6]` gives string `"2020-11-11 14:06:25"` and this should be valid format.

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to add my code, I have edited the question to include it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, cause I don't have much experience with Django, but I believe `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat` method will do the thing.

[image]

It gives you datetime object that hopefully can be digested by DateTimeField.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer, and more people will see it - so more people can help you.